# showing syntax error while create store procedure in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
    create procedure purchaseDetailsCheckOnDelete(p_purchaseDetailsId varchar(50))
    begin
        declare p_Exist tinyint(1);
        set p_Exist = False ;
        select p_Exist = (case  count(purchaseDetailsId) when '0' then False else True end  from tbl_PurchaseReturnDetails
        where (purchaseDetailsId = p_purchaseDetailsId) );
        select p_Exist ;

    end
```

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from
tbl_PurchaseReturnDetails
                where (purchaseDetailsId = p_purchaseDetailsId)' at line 5
```

Comment: no chance.. there is no Mising )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are determined to use parenthesis, then you're missing a `select`, viz

```
    select p_Exist = 
      (select case count(purchaseDetailsId)
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08caa/2)

Alternatively, drop the brackets

```
    select p_Exist = case count(purchaseDetailsId) 
              when '0' then False else True end  
       from tbl_PurchaseReturnDetails
       where purchaseDetailsId = p_purchaseDetailsId;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e619/1)

**Edit**

Shorter still:

```
    SELECT IFNULL((select 1 from tbl_PurchaseReturnDetails
       WHERE purchaseDetailsId = p_purchaseDetailsId), 0) AS p_Exist;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01eef/3)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create procedure purchaseDetailsCheckOnDelete(p_purchaseDetailsId varchar(50))
begin
    declare p_Exist tinyint(1);
    set p_Exist = False ;
    select p_Exist = case  count(purchaseDetailsId) when '0' then False else True end  from tbl_PurchaseReturnDetails
    where purchaseDetailsId = p_purchaseDetailsId;
    select p_Exist ;

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Every error message shows where the possible error is.
In your case it said, `... for the right syntax to use near 'from
tbl_PurchaseReturnDetails ...`.

When it says `near`, it means that the error is *before* that particular statement.
So the statement before `from` is wrong. You have put the closing brace at a wrong place.

***Change the statement***:

```
select p_Exist =
  ( case count(purchaseDetailsId) when '0' then False else True end
from tbl_PurchaseReturnDetails
  where (purchaseDetailsId = p_purchaseDetailsId) );
```

***to***:

```
select p_Exist =
  ( case count(purchaseDetailsId) when '0' then False else True end )
from tbl_PurchaseReturnDetails
  where (purchaseDetailsId = p_purchaseDetailsId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists purchaseDetailsCheckOnDelete;
create procedure purchaseDetailsCheckOnDelete(p_purchaseDetailsId varchar(50))
   begin
       declare p_Exist tinyint(1);
       set p_Exist = False ;
       select p_Exist = (case  count(purchaseDetailsId) when '0' then False else True end) as 'P_EXIST'
       from tbl_PurchaseReturnDetails
       where (purchaseDetailsId = p_purchaseDetailsId);
       select p_Exist ;
   end//
```